# How to create a vector with the values of a data frame classified by factors in R?

Tags: r, subset, r-factor

I have a data frame with values classified by levels (factors), so I want to create a vector with the values of an specific level, e.g.

```
A <- c("Case1", "Case3", "Case2", "Case3", "Case2",
       "Case1", "Case3", "Case2", "Case2", "Case3",
       "Case1", "Case1", "Case3", "Case1", "Case2")
Factors <- factor(A)
Values <- 1:15

DF <- data.frame(Factors, Values)

Values_of_Case1 <- DF$Values... ????
```

How to create a vector in order to obtain something like:

```
print(Values_of_Case1)
[1]  1  6 11 12 14
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DF$Values[DF$Factors == "Case1"]
[1]  1  6 11 12 14
```

or

```
subset(DF, Factors=='Case1')$Values
[1]  1  6 11 12 14
```

should work.

If you wanted only the row index for the matches you could do:

```
which(DF$Factors == "Case1")
[1]  1  6 11 12 14
```

Which in this case is the same, but it might not be in your use case.

Comment: Besides, I'd like to create a vector wuth the row numbers. How can I do it?

Comment: @DanielValenciaC. I updated the post with a way to get the row numbers.